# Is there any solution in antd react to check unsaved changes in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, state-management

I have a general component named `MyModal` and it is used in almost 20+ components inside my web-app, I use ant-d modal. Now I have to check that, is there any unsaved changes inside the child component from `MyModal`: if so, then prompt the user. I can check one by one from each and every child component, by using a new state, but I don't want to do this, infect I want it to be precise and controllable from one component i.e. MyModal component.

How can I check the state changes in the child component (rendered in `MyModal`)

---

### MY CODE STRUCTURE

> MyModal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'antd'
    
class MyModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal {...this.props}>
        {this.props.children}
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

export default  MyModal
```

> ChildComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Input, Button } from 'antd'
import MyModal from '../components/MyModal'
    
class ChildComponent extends Component {
  this.state = {
    value: '',
    visible: false,
  };

  onChangeValue = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  toggleModal = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  handleOk = () => alert('hello world!')

  render() {
    const { visible, value } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
          Open Modal
        </Button>
        <MyModal visible={visible} onClose={this.toggleModal} footer={[
            <Button key="back" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
              Return
            </Button>,
            <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={this.handleOk}>
              Submit
            </Button>,
          ]}
        >
        <Input value={value} onChange={this.onChangeValue} />
        {/* this is an example component to show you my problem, there are 
            a lot of more fields and states too. */}
      </MyModal>
    )
  }
}

export default  ChildComponent
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@heyamberwilkie/adding-an-unsaved-changes-prompt-to-a-redux-form-5fab7e4e181a

Comment: I already read this article & this is not my scenario. My scenario is whenever a Modal is going to be close, it should check is there any unsaved changes inside the child component or not. I can do this in every child component where MyModal is used, but I don't want that method, I want it simple like from it should check from parent component (i.e. MyModal) not by child components.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that really unless you are willing to introduce some kind of callback to inform the parent when the children are in an unsaved state. React router has ways to prevent navigation, but it is going to need criteria to use to.do so, which again would mean some kind of state being updated by a callback.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `Form.Provider` from `antd` and wrapped all the child components in the `Form.Provider` like below.

```
  const changedFormsObj = {
    accommodationForm: false,
    userProfileForm: false,
  }



<Form.Provider
  onFormChange={(name) => {
    changedFormsObj[name] = true;
  }}
  onFormFinish={(name) => {
    changedFormsObj[name] = false;
  }}
>
  {children}
</Form.Provider>
```

When there is a change in any child form component `onFormChange` method will be triggered with the name of the form in the `Form.Provider` with that we can set a flag for all the forms and when there is form submit `onFormFinish` method will be triggered with the name of the form. With this two we can decide whether the form changes are saved or not for all the forms in the parent component itself.

For the more info check the below link.

https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Provider